# statistics finding the confidence level of the interval estimate medical expenses

Tags: probability, statistics, confidence-interval

A confidence interval for the true mean of the annual medical expenses of a middle-class American family is given as ($ 738, $ 777). If this interval is based on interviews with 110 families and a standard deviation of $ 120 is assumed. Suppose all annual medical expenses of middle-class American families follow an approximately normal distribution.

(a) What is the sample mean of annual medical expenses?

sample mean = 777 + 738 / 2
            = 757.5

---

(b) What is the confidence level of the interval estimate (as a decimal)

CI = sample mean + z alpha/2 * (standard deviation / square root n)

Isolate for z alpha/2

777 = 757.5 + z alpha/2 * (120/square root 110)

Rearrange

(777 * square root 110) / (757.5 * 120) = z alpha/2

```
                        0.089650657 = z alpha/2
```

What are the correct solutions and answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Foremost, you are told that the standard deviation of the expenses is assumed to be $\sigma = 120$.  This is your first hint that the confidence interval was derived using a normal distribution, not a student's $t$ distribution, because the latter uses the **sample variance** $s$ that is calculated from the data.

Thus, you have correctly inferred that the interval has the form $$[738, 777] = [L, U] = \left[\bar x - z_{\alpha/2} \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}},\; \bar x + z_{\alpha/2} \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}\right].$$  It follows that $$\bar x = \frac{L + U}{2} = \frac{738+777}{2}$$ as you again correctly compute.  It also follows that $$z_{\alpha/2} \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} = \frac{U - L}{2},$$ which is a quantity usually given the name "margin of error."  Hence the **critical value** $$z_{\alpha/2} = \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sigma} \times \frac{U - L}{2} \approx 1.70431,$$ and if you recall, this means $$\Pr[Z > z_{\alpha/2}] = \Pr[Z > 1.70431] = \alpha/2,$$ where $Z$ is the standard normal distribution.  So you would either use a calculator or a normal distribution table to find that $\alpha/2 \approx 0.0441612$, which means that the provided confidence interval corresponds to a significance level of about $\alpha = 0.088$, or $100(1-\alpha)\% = 91.17\%$ confidence.

Answer (score 1):

There is an algebra error while isolating the variable

> 777 = 757.5 + z alpha/2 * (120/square root 110)

In the next step, you seem to be multiplying "square root 110" through out. May I ask why ?

Comment: Hi, I have gotten 1.704314378 for z alpha/2 if that is correct

I subtracted 757.5 both sides,

Got 19.5...

19.5 / 11.44 ...

1.70.

Is this correct?

Comment: That looks good! 1.7 is the critical value. You still have to find the confidence level..

Comment: Wait how do you do that again... I look at the t distributions table. I found degrees of freedom 27 then it goes to 0.05 for upper tail probability for critical value 1.704. Is the answer 95%? It points to 0.05 ?

Comment: 0.95 looks fine. Using ztable you get 0.9554  : http://prntscr.com/ekj50q